# How to merge string from a stream and return another stream

Tags: java, string, java-stream

I am trying to process quite a big file that contain a chat history export. The looks like that :

```
[26/03/2021 08:52:53] Nick1: ‎message 1
[26/03/2021 08:59:30] Nick2: message 2
--
as a multiline block
[26/03/2021 09:11:31] Nick1: message 3
```

I am processing this file using this code :

```
final Stream<String> lineStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).lines();
```

This code will return a stream consisting of each line one by one, the thing is that I would like to have a stream of **messages**, I would like to merge the multi-line messages block.

I would like to be able to give a rule like

> it must start with a [, have a timestamp, and finish with a ]

to be able to detect a new message start, as I would like to prevent any error if a multi-line message could use [ on a new line.

I really want to have a stream in return, of a Message class that I will create. This message class will have a string parameter constructor.

I don't know what I could use after on my lineStream to transform it into a stream of Message.

I don't want to have a list as the result, I want to have a lazy stream (like the line() method return), as the input could be quite big, so processing it and storing it into a list is not a viable solution, the new stream will be processed with a forEach call to process each Message instance.

If the input is something like several gigabytes, storing the result in a list could be too big in the memory.

PS: using jdk 15, I can then use quite modern code.

Comment: I'll make you one.

Comment: There you go: https://pastebin.com/6u3CVYVz

Comment: Somebody closed this, but I allready made it so hope you still check it out

Comment: I made it so that you could just keep using the stream. To iterate the messages.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to make it re-opened as they mark it as a duplicate as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49159058/read-in-multiple-lines-from-a-file-and-combine-them-into-one-line-based-on-a-st where the result is a list, this is not ideal if several gigabyte is to be processed, I will try your code, thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, if the question is re-opened I will gladly accept your solution, I have some errors, but it is because I didn't gave you all the possibilities in the message content that there are wrong aggregations, but nothing I can't solve.

Comment: I basically took the method '.lines()' of the BufferedReader and rewrote it. If the regex pattern is not ok, just change it as needed. And yes you are correct using streams or iterators is way better than storing everything inside a list in the RAM. Always use streams if possible

Comment: please do so, since the other post does not use streams and is therefore a different approach. I can't vote for reopen myself though

Comment: @dreamcrash I did vote for a re-open and edited my question by adding the fact that I want it to works on lazy stream to be able to minimize the memory usage

Comment: @IntoVoid I will have to adapt the regex, indeed, but really, thank you for your code, it was exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: @iXô I'm really glad to hear that. Enjoy